# Default behavior of DNS with Proxy

Tags: dns, proxy

I have a browser (FF) using proxy, with *use this proxy server for all protocols* option enabled. How will DNS behave? Will it go through proxy as well?

Background:

I want to monitor and modify my network traffic, using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9465236/python-twisted-proxy-and-modifying-content) simple proxy written with [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) as an example

Answer (score 1):

"use this proxy server for all protocols " probably means all protocols used in the URL

i.e.

- HTTP in http://www.example.com/index.html
- SSL in https://www.example.com/checkout.html
- FTP in ftp://ftp.example.com/pub/war_and_peace.txt

It does not mean every protocol that might be used by the OS in servicing this request

- ARP
- ICMP
- DNS
- SMB
- …

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your local DNS settings can resolve your proxy server domain,then it will go through the remote proxy server as well.When I use firefox,local dns server can resolve a proxy server domain,but with [GFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall_of_China) DNS pollution,I cannot browser twitter.But I can open twitter website when the proxy is on.

Comment: Could you give some more details?

Comment: all DNS servers in China has DNS pollution,but when I use a proxy(firefox FoxyProxy,HTTP proxy),the pollution does not work any more.

Comment: I was not clear, I meant that I don't understand how actuall I should *make sure that your local DNS settings can resolve your proxy server domain*